# Php session is not being remembered

Tags: php, jquery, session, get

**First, some info about the project**

The issue is happening in a website i am developing in php. We decided to use a different subdomain for our JSON api, as such:

Subdomain we are in: tickets.example.com
JSON location: api.example.com/json

In order to log in to the ticket system we are developing, we send a get request to a php script, that returns the result as a json-string.

**The problem**

It seems that php can't see that we have a session allready created, when we send a request to our login script. While we allready have a PHPSESSID cookie set, i for some reason get a new session id in the response headers.

You could say "Hey, different subdomains. Of course it won't work!"

I would of thought this myself, but using a cookie editor to change the session id to the one in the Set-cookie header on the response logs me in.

**Flow of data**

*For lack of better name*

Step 1: Request is sendt via jquery, like this:

```
$('#loginForm').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( 'http://api.website.com/json/login.php', $('#loginForm').serialize(), function(data) {
        if(data.result==true)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
        else
        {
            error(data.message);
        }
       },
       'json'
    );
});
```

As you can see, if we get result=true in the json-file, the website should reload(And display the logged in site). This happens, but because of something wrong in the session handling, we are set to "logged in" in another session id.

This is the request sendt, and the response headers:

[image http://puu.sh/anKCX/75701a8891.png](http://puu.sh/anKCX/75701a8891.png)

As you can see, we get a Set-cookie header, telling us to set the cookie PHPSESSID to something. This is never actually done, and the cookie stays the same as before login (r71qijt6utua4qjgarm59oe535)

Changing the cookie to our new session id logs us in, as i mentioned.

**The code**

Here are some snippets:

*login.php*

```
<?php
require_once 'utils.php'; //Runs session_start();

[...]

if (!Utils::isAuthenticated()) {
    if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
        isset($_POST['password']) &&
        !empty($_POST['username']) &&
        !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);

        if (UserHandler::userExists($username)) {
            $user = UserHandler::getUserByName($username);
            $storedPassword = $user->getPassword();

            if ($password == $storedPassword) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
[...]
```

Comment: do you call `session_start`?

Comment: Yes, in utils.php. It is require_once'd everywhere, so that shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `session_set_cookie_params`. According to the docs this function:

> Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.
>
> This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get().

By specifying `.example.com` instead of `exchange.example.com` or `api.example.com` you create a wildcard cookie that can be used across all subdomains. The `0` means that this is a session cookie that will expire at the end of your browsing session (such as when the browser is closed) and the `/` here just specifies that the cookie is set at the root of your site.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com'); 
session_start();
```

**Reference:** [`session_set_cookie_params(...);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

**Note:** Make sure you place `session_set_cookie_params(...);` before you're call to `session_start();` as it references the values that you're setting. If you place it after `session_start();` the values will be updated after the session cookie has already been set defeating the purpose of running this function.

Comment: It looks like the cookie allready is set to .example.com, though

Comment: @LiamS.Crouch Sorry I may be missing it. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Doesn't it say in "Set-Cookie" under "Response headers" in the image, or am i misunderstanding it?